systemd: PrivateTmp without PrivateMounts?
Problem: I need to do remote file system maintenance (mount, unmount, encrypt, and so on) with Apache. I like PrivateTmp, but PrivateMounts just causes a vast amount of extra work.
So: is it possible to run a PrivateTmp service without also enabling PrivateMounts? At first sight, it seems not. If I add an override file (/etc/systemd/system/apache2.service.d/override.conf, on Ubuntu 22.04), or run systemctl edit apache2, and add
[Service]
PrivateMounts=false

then it makes no difference. If I restart Apache systemd-analyze security apache2 still reports that PrivateMounts is on. The docs for PrivateMounts more or less state this ("Other file system namespace unit settings — PrivateTmp=, … — also enable file system namespacing in a fashion equivalent to this option").
Any suggestions for other options? I've tried double-forking/daemonizing the scripts that actually do the work, but they still somehow are incapable of mounting a filesystem that's visible to anything outside Apache (how does the script even know that it's long-deceased grandparent was Apache?)

The script doesn't know it's a descendent of Apache, but it still inherits the mount namespace no matter how many forks you do.

@muru: makes sense, thanks. My best solution so far is to run the maintenance script at now +1 minute, which works, at the expense of having to asynchronously find out whether or not the script succeeded.

@EML that is a strong anti-pattern. You break the chain of custody there, and combine two job executing controllers (systemd and atd), so that if something goes wrong, you wouldn't necessarily know into which logs to look. I mean, the moment you run something as at, all the things you've set up with systemd, including the private tmp namespace, are of course no longer applicable. So, that's definitely not what fulfills your title's requirements.

@MarcusMüller: well... that's why I said 'best solution so far'. Actually, it's my only solution so far, if you exclude restarting Apache without PrivateTmp, doing the work, restoring PrivateTmp, daemon-reload, etc. Any solution has to (preferably temporarily) defeat PrivateMounts by definition.

@EML no, it doesn't have to, that's a false logical step there. And your at approach it's not a solution, either, not even a bad one – you don't get the private tmp that way.

Private tmp is a filesystem namespacing feature; it is a private namespace mount. You can't have a private tmp without a private mount namespace!
So, no, there's no way to achieve what you want.
Personally, I'd probably look to other mechanisms that would make this better; keep the mount namespacing. With templated systemd units, you can do your filesystem operations on the initial namespace instead of your private one, if necessary (really be sure it's necessary – not allowing a process to pollute the global namespace does sound like a very good idea, in principle). Worst case, systemd-run can run what you need to be done globally for you. But all you list sound like it could be done "safely" and "sanely" with systemd-cryptsetup, systemd-mount etc.
